# calling jquery from ajax page

Tags: jquery

I'm having trouble using jQuery with child page

parent.html loads child.html like so: ie user clicks

```
<a href="#" id="n-email">
```

JQuery

```
$('a#n-email').click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/scripts/contact.js",
        dataType: "script"
    });

    $('#content').load("child.htm");
});
```

contact.js

```
$(function () {
    alert("contact js hit");
});
```

This occasionally works. But I can't work out the logic of why it works. I've also tried adding a ref to the Jquery on the handler also.  I feel like I'm missing a trick here.

Thanks to jake + lucus. I've got the following working. Needs a refactor, but works

```
$('#n-email').click(function () {
    var e = this; reset(e);

    var mypage = $('#contentemail').load("email.php");

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/scripts/contact.js",
        dataType: "script",
        success: function (mypage) {
            $(document).append(mypage);
        }
    });

    $('#contentemail').show();

});
```

Comment: I fixed a typo (I hope).  You originally had the id of the anchor tag as "a-email" but refer to it as "n-email" in your js.

Comment: what works occasionally? the alert()? or the .load("child.htm")?

Comment: quick tip: instead of $('a#n-email'), it would be faster to write $('#n-email')

Comment: thanks for edit,  just a typo in my post. 

harshath, the load alway works. It's calling the alert in contact.js that's not working. I wish to add more functionality in contact.js. Actually i want child.htm to contain a form which i submit via ajax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to put a callback function in the jQuery ajax using the success property. 
Second, you cant just put javascript en a html element. That just doenst work. You could try using eval.
Try this code as a start:

```
$('a #n-email').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: "/scripts/contact.js",
          dataType: "script",
          success: function(value){eval(value)}
        });     
});
```

Comment: thank lucas. do you mind explaining how the eval would work

Maybe i could be clearer what i'm trying to do. 

- Parent loads child
- child contains a contact form which i needs to have validation etc.

Comment: eval execute javascript from text. In this case that is the text that came from the ajax response.

Answer (score 1):

Using $(document).append(content) will strip out all script tags from content and attempt to evaluate them. So you could go

```
$('a #n-email').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: "/scripts/contact.js",
          dataType: "script",
          success: function(result)
          {
              $(document).append(result);
          }
        });     
});
```